# Number of binary palindromes in a range

Tags: algorithms, binary, palindrome

I want to find the number of binary palindromes from $1$ to $N$.

$0 \lt N \lt 2^{32}-1$.

I observed a pattern that if we have an odd-length binary palindrome, it can generate only $1$ even-length palindrome by adding a digit.

If we have an even-length binary palindrome, it can generate $2$ odd-length palindromes by adding another digit.

How do I solve the problem with or without using this observation?

Comment: Is `N` always represented as a 32-digit number, or is it represented with the minimum number of digits required in order to represent it?

Comment: N is some positive integer in base 10.
Say, we have to find the number of binary palindromes upto 500. So, N equals 500.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose $m$ is a palindrome. Any positive binary integer has first digit $1$, so $m$ has last digit $1$, and if $m$ has $k$ digits and $k > 1$, this leaves $k - 2$ digits. If $k$ is even, so is $k - 2$, and since $m$ is a palindrome, the (free) choice of the first $\frac{1}{2}(k - 2)$ of the remaining digits determines the last $\frac{1}{2} (k - 2)$ of the remaining digits, and so there are $2^{(k - 2) / 2}$ binary palindromes of even length $k$.

Similarly, if $k$ is odd, the free choice of the first $\frac{1}{2}(k - 1) $ digits determines the last $\frac{1}{2} (k - 3)$ of the digits. and so there are $2^{(k - 1) / 2}$ binary palindromes of odd length $k$.

Of course, in the special case that $k = 1$ there is just one palindrome, namely $1$ itself (and so the above general formula for odd $k$ extends to this case too).

Comment: Cool. How do I use this to find number of palindromes uptil the positive integer N?

Comment: If $N$ has $k$ digits, this tells you immediately how many palindromes there are of length $< k$ digits, leaving undetermined just the number of $k$-digit palindromes $< N$, which can in turn figure out quickly by considering the 2nd through $\lceil \frac{k}{2} \rceil$th digits of $N$ and applying a similar counting argument.

Answer (score 1):

The palindromes of length $2n$ are in bijection with the binary numbers of length $n$ (with leading bit $1$!): write the binary number, followed by its reverse to obtain the palindrome belonging to a number.
The palindromes of length $2n-1$ are also in bijection with the binary numbers of length $n$ (with leading bit $1$!): write the binary number, followed by its reverse, but skip the first bit of the reverse, to obtain the palindrome belinging to a number.

If you sum over all lengths $1,\ldots , 32$, this means that we run over all binary number of lentgth $1$ to $16$ twice. Hence the total is $2\cdot (2^{16}-1)$.